# Multiple Patterns in Regex

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

Can there be multiple patterns in Regexp_Replace.

Pattern 1 :  `'^#.*'`

Pattern 2:  `'^//.*'`

Pattern 3 : `'^&&.*'`

I want all three patterns in same regexp_replace function like

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE ('Unit testing last level','Pattern 1,Pattern 2,Pattern 3','',1,0,'m') 
  from dual;
```

Comment: Try  an alternation group - `'^(#|//|&&).*'`

Comment: Not like how you asked. But you can user a regex `|` OR operator. You need to define how it should be the replacement.

Comment: Are these homework questions? 3 `REGEX` questions in a row.

Comment: Please have a look at [mcve] to improve your question. What do you need to do? Please post some sample data and needed result to clarify your need.

Comment: @Wiktor Thanks It worked

Comment: @Wikitor I did thanks once again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an alternation group where all alternative branches are `|`-separated.

```
^(#|//|&&).*
```

The `(...)` form a grouping construct where you may place your various `#`, `&&`, and other possible "branches". A `|` is an alternation operator.

The pattern will match:

- `^` - start of a line (as you are passing `m` match_parameter)
- `(#|//|&&)`  - either `#`, `//` or `&&`
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than a newline (since `n` match_parameter is not used).